# Headers nelmio API doc

Tags: symfony, header, nelmioapidocbundle

I want to define a parameter in Headers in sandbox of Nelmio API Doc Bundle.

How can I define this in annotation of Nelmio ApiDoc ?

```
 @ApiDoc(
       resource=true,
       description="Return the information",
       requirements={
           {
               "name"="ref",
               "dataType"="integer",
               "requirement"="\d{1,6}",
               "description"="Ref"
           }
       },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
requirements={
           {
               "HTTP_name"="ref",
               "HTTP_dataType"="integer",
               "HTTP_requirement"="\d{1,6}",
               "HTTP_description"="Ref"
           }
```